# Xcode 4.5 UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a question regarding UITableView on Xcode. I have text in the cell but when I test it, it doesn't show. I just started programming so any help would be appreciated. If anyone can email me so I can provide the project file that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be aware of how table views work. I would suggest carefully reading some of the excellent online documentation on this topic, including sample code if available.

You will need to remember that the system is responsible for deciding which parts of the table view are supposed to be visible, then asking your code to provide the details of what should be seen.

If you have actually provided the routine to provide the contents of the cell, try putting in a breakpoint or some logging to ensure that your code is being called. If so, start by returning something simple and verifying that this is displayed.

Also, prepare code with an explanation of what it is doing to add to the question. You never know, just doing that may clarify to you what is going wrong. If not, post it up and give someone else a chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really directly solve your problem because you surprisingly haven't given code so as far as I know you could be missing a semicolon! (JK)

This is a detailed answer I gave to someone a while ago, very relevant to your situation

But for a table view use this code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];


    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"]
                autorelease];


        cell.textLabel.text = nil;                


    }

    if (cell) {

        //customization 
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Text Label";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

You say you are starting coding.... let me explain. First of try picking up the book:

The Big Nerd Ranch Guide

I suggest you read a heck load of books to get you juiced up on language and API and programming skills

Dequeuing is basically nilling and cacheing any cell that is not visible, aka you scroll past it. Therefore, `cell == nil` will be called in probably four situations (that I can think of):

When we first setup the table view (cells will be nil)
When we reload data
Whenever we may arrive at this class
When the cells becomes invisible from the table view
So, the identifier for dequeuing is like an ID. Then in the statement to see if cell is nil, we initialize cell, you can see the overridden init method: initWithStyle. This is just what type of cell there is, there are different types with different variables you can customize. I showed you the default. Then we use the reuseIdentifier which was the dequeuing identifier we said earlier. THEY MUST MATCH! I `nil` textLabel just for better structure, in this case each cell has the same text so it won't matter really. It makes it so the cell that dequeues comes back with the right customization you implemented. Then once cell is actually valid, we can customize.

Also, you are using the same text for each cell. If you do want to have different text for each cell, familiar yourself with NSArray. Then you could provide the array count in numberOfRowsForSection and then do something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

Where indexPath is the NSIndexPath argument provided in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. The row variable is the row number, so everything fits!

Wow, that was a lot to take in right! Now go stop being an objective-c noob and start reading some books!

For more info read:

[Table View Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)